# Filter files by Date (in CMD)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, pipe

I created in Windows 8.1 a file a month ago approximately. I am looking for it but I do not find it (I have a lot of files), so I remember ONLY a word of their content "otro" (in spanish) but I get a lot of files. I would like to filter files by Date (because I know that I created the file a month ago approximately).

To filter by file content I am using:

```
findstr /s /i /n /c:"otro" *.txt
```

I need to add to that command other filter (by date). I think that I need to add a pipe plus a command which filter by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to sort files by date with `dir /od`, but that doesn't work across subfolders. But to narrow down to a single month, you can use:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b /od /a-d *.txt') do @(find /i "otro" "%i" >nul &&echo %~ti %i|findstr /b "05....2016")
```

(this is for use on command line. For use in a batchfile double all `%`).

Finds all `.txt` files in current folder and any subfolders that contain `otro` and were modified in May this year (now in the middle of June, that's about "four weeks ago plus/minus two weeks") (assuming a date-format of `mm/dd/yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy` or `mm.dd.yyyy`; for `dd.mm.yyyy` format use `findstr /b "...05.2016"`). I hope, there are not too many of them...

Comment: Does `find` set ERRORLEVEL correctly? Also, this depends on the locale setting for the date format. It will likely be different outside of en/US.

Comment: @Liturgist I never found `find`-errorlevel to give me false results.Do you have a counterexample?. And yes, this _is_ locale dependent (_"assuming a date format of ..."_) It _could_ be made generic with `wmic datafile`, but that would be  slooow and too much code for a (probably) one-time-task.

Comment: Thank you Stephan :) . I found my file thanks to your code, I only changed that you said "date-format" to "...05.2016". It is really interesting that it is possible to use a loop in command line (I did not know), I am going to study the code. I mark your answer as the solution.